# Populate Text Field from Drop-Down in LiveCycle by Adding to the Value

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am populating a text field from a drop-down menu in LiveCycle and have the basics in place (thanks to previous posts). I would like a second text field to populate the second selection from the drop-down menu but I am having difficulty.

Drop-Down Menu = January (Value is 1 or first choice), February (2), March, etc.

When a user selects "January" (the first choice from the drop-down) I would like the text field to populate "February" or the second choice from the drop-down. It currently displays the user selection:

this.rawValue = xfa.event.newText;

I am not sure how to add to the raw.Value to display the 2nd or 3rd choice from the drop-down. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList1.selectedIndex will give you the dropdown selected index. 
The following javascript may help you,

```
DropDownList1.selectedIndex= DropDownList1.selectedIndex+1

TextField1.rawValue = DropDownList1.rawValue;
```

Hope this is helpful.